# Limit jQuery to do actions in more than one element

Tags: jquery

We have a tooltip that opens if you press a link, with jQuery 'toggleclass'. There are two cases, with slightly different html. That's the code of each one.

**Case 1:**

```js
$(".tooltip").parent().find("a").click(function() {
      $(".tooltip").toggleClass('on');
     });
```

```css
 .tooltip {display:none}
    .on {display:block}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <label>
     <span>
          Some text <a href="#">Open tooltip</a>
        </span>
    </label>

    <div class="tooltip">
    This is the tooltip text
    </div>
```

**Case 2:**

```js
    $(".tooltip").parent().find("a").click(function() {
      $(".tooltip").toggleClass('on');
     });
```

```css
    .tooltip {display:none}
    .on {display:block}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Some text</label> 
<span>Another text <a href="#">Open tooltip</a></span>
<div class="tooltip">This is the tooltip text</div>
```

That works without problem, but now we have a page with two tooltip pieces, as this:

```js
    $(".tooltip").parent().find("a").click(function() {
      $(".tooltip").toggleClass('on');
     });
```

```css
    .tooltip {display:none}
    .on {display:block}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>
     <span>
          Some text <a href="#">Open tooltip</a>
        </span>
    </label>

    <div class="tooltip">
    This is the tooltip text
    </div> 

<label>
     <span>
          Some text <a href="#">Open tooltip</a>
        </span>
    </label>

    <div class="tooltip">
    This is the tooltip text
    </div>
```

As you can see, this code open both tooltips. I'm pretty sure there will be some selector in jQuery that allows us to find the closest tooltip to the link, but we have tried with ***$(this).parents().find(".tooltip")***, and ***$(this).closest(".tooltip")***, but without success.

How can I prevent both tooltips to open, but without changing the HTML code?

Answer (score 0):

When your `<a>` is clicked you need to go up to the label and move to the `.next('.tooltip')`. There are better ways to structure your HTML to make this easier but the below works as expected.

```js
    $(".tooltip").parent().find("a").click(function() {
      $(this).parents('label').next('.tooltip').toggleClass('on');
     });
```

```css
    .tooltip {display:none}
    .on {display:block}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>
     <span>
          Some text <a href="#">Open tooltip</a>
        </span>
    </label>

    <div class="tooltip">
    This is the tooltip text
    </div> 

<label>
     <span>
          Some text <a href="#">Open tooltip</a>
        </span>
    </label>

    <div class="tooltip">
    This is the tooltip text
    </div>
```

As noted in the comments, you have 2 different structures for your HTML, one where the `span` containing the `a` is a child of `label` and the other where it is a sibling. If you want to keep this idea (which IMO is a bad idea!) then you can have some logic to try to determine where to find the right `.tooltip`.

```js
$(".tooltip").parent().find("a").click(function() {
    var $tt = $(this).parents('label').next('.tooltip');
    if($tt.length == 0){
      $tt = $(this).parents('span').next('.tooltip');
    }
    $tt.toggleClass('on');
});
```

```css
.tooltip {display:none}
    .on {display:block}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>
     <span>
          Some text <a href="#">Open tooltip</a>
        </span>
    </label>

    <div class="tooltip">
    This is the tooltip text
    </div> 

<label>
     <span>
          Some text <a href="#">Open tooltip</a>
        </span>
    </label>

    <div class="tooltip">
    This is the tooltip text
    </div>

<label>
     A label
    </label>
<span>
          Some text <a href="#">Open tooltip</a>
        </span>
    <div class="tooltip">
    This is the tooltip text
    </div>
```

Comment: @Arkana - Just noticed you have a different structure of html for that example (`span` is a sibling of `label` in (2) but a child of it in (1)) - there's no "one size fits all" here, you need to standardize how you will structure your links/tooltips or have a different solution for each structure.

Comment: See updated example. You should standardize your HTML layout.